# iMacros can fill out a web form and submit it, but can the data come from a (local) XML source?

Tags: xml, imacros

iMacros works great to record a macro of the actions required to fill out a web form for later automation. However, I'd like to get the data for the form's fields from an XML source on my hard drive. iMacros doesn't seem to provide features for XML parsing (that I could find). Is it possible?

My motivation is that I want to import/convert (possibly using Chrome) [HotPotatoes JQuiz](http://hotpot.uvic.ca/wintutor6/jquiz1.htm) files (stored in XML on my local drive) for use on [Mentimeter](https://www.mentimeter.com/). I realize I could write a Java program to output the iMacro file (a sort of programmatic hard-coding), but want to avoid this solution.

Comment: you can load xml files in the browser and scrape data as on regular web page

Comment: that's a great idea, @Bestmacros

Answer (score 1):

You can use csv as seen in this example:

http://wiki.imacros.net/Form_Filling

Save information in `CSV` format and read lines